# Have UICollectionViewFlowLayout behave as iOS home screen for insert and delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

When removing or deleting items from a UICollectionView with the default UICollectionViewFlowLayout, all other items move to their new positions at the same time.

When deleting apps form the iOS home screen, it looks like every row is being adjust one after another giving a nice looking animation / effect.

How can one achieve the same with a UICollectionView?